# How to add marginal notes on the right in `ltxdoc` document class

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote

I am having an issue inserting marginal notes while using the `ltxdoc` document class. I see that the default layout is the following:

[image: ltxdoc layout]

From what I understand, the margin notes are set up this way because the `\DescribeMacro` command places the macro name as a marginal note. I would like to utilize the right margins for inserting my own marginal notes. I tried using

```
\reversemarginpar\marginpar{Some text to be placed in the right margin}
```

but this did not do what I wanted. I have also tried using the `marginnote` package to no avail...

```
\marginnote{Still not on the right}
```

How can I place text in the right margin? Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\rmarginpar}[1]{\reversemarginpar\marginpar{#1}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\marginpar{This marginal note is on the left. This behavior is expected based on
    the page layout.}
\rmarginpar{This marginal note is also on the left, but I want it to appear on the
    right of the text.
    Even worse, this marginal note overlaps the first note.}
\marginnote[This is on the left, as expected]{}[1in]
\marginnote{This should be on the right of the text.}[2in]

\end{document}
```

### Update 2016/03/08

I have also tried using the `marginfix` and `mparhack` packages. These did not fix my issues, either. The only improvement is that loading the `marginfix` package made the `\marginpar`'s no longer overlap, but that is not what I am trying to fix.

Comment: The class is already using `\reversemarginpar`, I think.... But since you want double margin pars, that's more of a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this that uses the `tabto` package.  The top of the `\rmarginpar` should be on the call line. I provide an optional argument to give vertical shift to the `\rmarginpar`, to help the user avoid overlap.

In the MWE below, I use red for the `\rmarginpar`, just to see more easily what has been added.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tabto,xcolor}
\newcommand\rmarginpar[2][0pt]{\leavevmode%
  \tabto*{\dimexpr\linewidth+10pt}\smash{\raisebox{%
  \dimexpr.6\ht\strutbox+#1}{\parbox[t]{2.5cm}{%
    \scriptsize\color{red}\raggedright#2}}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{This marginal note is on the left. This behavior is expected based on
    the page layout.}
\rmarginpar[20pt]{This marginal note that is made
   to appear on the right of the text.
    I have shifted it up by 20 pt.}
\marginnote[This is on the left, as expected]{}[1in]
\marginnote{This should be on the right of the text.}[2in]
\lipsum[2]
And now here is the third paragraph.
\rmarginpar{Another right marginpar, this one lowered a line.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Steven B. Segletes! It looks like this will work nicely for my needs.

Many of the commands you use (`leavevmode`, `dimexpr`, `smash`, `ht`, `strutbox`) are foreign to me. A brief explanation or link to an explanation of these would be appreciated so that I can fully understand this solution.

Comment: @AnthonyMottaz `\leavevmode` exits "vertical" (page) mode, entering "horizontal" (paragraph) mode.  This affects some commands that otherwise appear at the beginning of a paragraph. `\dimexpr` treats the following quantities as lengths, allowing simple addition and subtraction operations therein. `\smash` creates its argument with zero height and depth. `\ht` followed by a box name yields a length equal to the height (above the baseline) of the box (`\dp` is the depth below the baseline of the box that follows).  `\strutbox` is a zero-width vertical box that spans one complete line of text.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found one solution using the `tikzpagenodes` package. I defined a new command `\rmarginpar` which places a `tikz` node where I want it.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\rmarginpar}[1]{
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] {%
\node[anchor = west, xshift = \textwidth, text width = {\oddsidemargin - 2ex}]
    {#1};
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{This marginal note is on the left. This behavior is expected based on
    the page layout.}
\lipsum[2]
\rmarginpar{Hooray! I got this on the right of the text!}

\end{document}
```

I still have a few problems with this method:

1. It feels pretty "hacky"... this has nothing to do with normal margin notes. I am just calculation a location to place some text on a page.
2. The text is vertically centered where it is inserted. I would prefer the vertical placement of text to behave like a normal `\marginpar`.
3. Multiple notes overlap each other, and now the `marginfix` package has no hope of fixing that issue.

Perhaps someone else has a better idea?

### Update: 2016/03/11

The solution above has another major issue. Specifically, notes entered using `\rmarginpar` as defined above must be entered after a line break or paragraph break, since otherwise `xshift` will push the note off the page. For example:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\rmarginpar}[1]{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] {%
\node[anchor = west, xshift = \textwidth, text width = {\oddsidemargin - 2ex}]
    {#1};
    }%
}

\begin{document}
This is a sentence. Here is another one, but this one is a bit longer. Short 
sentence. A medium length sentence. 

\rmarginpar{I need a new line or new paragraph for this note to appear.}
This is a sentence. Here is another one, 
but this one is a bit longer. Short sentence. A medium length sentence. This is 
a sentence. Here is another one, but this one is a bit longer. Short sentence. 
A medium length sentence. This is a sentence. Here is another one, but this one 
is a bit longer. Short sentence.
\rmarginpar{This margin note does not appear since the \texttt{xshift} pushes 
it off the page.}
 A medium length sentence. This is a sentence. Here is another one, but this 
 one is a bit longer. Short sentence. A medium length sentence. This is a 
 sentence. Here is another one, but this one is a bit longer. Short sentence. A 
 medium length sentence. This is a sentence. Here is another one, but this one 
 is a bit longer. Short sentence. A medium length sentence.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]